# How to know if a persistent MQTT session is still available?

Tags: mqtt

This is a general question about the MQTT protocol and using MQTT clients. In particular I am using mosquitto as a server and ruby-mqtt as a client.

MQTT offers the concept of *persistent sessions* meaning that former subscriptions are kept and messages with qos > 0 are queued while a client is disconnected. That means for my client implementation I could skip *subscribing* after connecting to the broker, except for the very first time.

The question is: how can I be sure that my subscriptions are still there? I imagine that there could be a case where a new server is started which has no information about my former session and thus my subscriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To contradict my co-answerers, MQTT v3.1.1 provides a mechanism for the broker to tell a client that is reconnecting that a session was restored. This is the "session present" flag provided during the CONNACK message.

Clients/brokers that say they support MQTT v3.1.1 should support this flag. For example, the Paho 1.0 clients should all do so (the Python client certainly does) and the upcoming 1.4 release of mosquitto adds support for this flag to its existing support for MQTT v3.1.1.

It's also worth noting that this *is* a useful feature now that MQTT v3.1.1 requires that retained messages be transmitted on each SUBSCRIBE, regardless of whether a subscription existed previously.

Comment: Ah thanks man that is the answer I was hoping for. It is not that I have a urgent need for saving that few bytes right now, but I wanted to be sure that it is possible to make reasonable use of the persistence feature. Before v3.1.1 I was wondering if it would be a solution to publish a retained message to a 'private' topic such as 'sessions/<client_id>/'. When reconnecting I would receive the retained message immediately and thus not need to subscribe again. You think thats a reasonable workaround?

Comment: Not really, because retained messages and persistent clients could be treated differently. Mosquitto can be configured to remove old persistent clients for example, but not retained messages.

Comment: @ralight ... I lost this flag in the CONNACK message. My M2Mqtt support for MQTT 3.1.1 is under development ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Brokers implementing persistent sessions should be storing that info to disk/db so it survives over a restart. Enterprise brokers (e.g. IBM MQ) can even federate this information across multiple broker instances to provide fail over.

Having said that, what do you actually save by skipping requesting the subscription again?

Comment: Well, what I actually save would be the transmission of the subscription messages, which could be helpful in scenarios of periodically reconnecting clients (low-energy tracking device over gsm for example). But thx for the answer!

Comment: @hardillb - brokers are now allowed to discard state, so there is no guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in MQTT protocol specification to know if your subscriptions are there.

It depends on the broker : it could support a permanent storage to save persistent subscriptions to avoid lost them in the case of a fault (shutdown).

On the client side, based on the protocol, you know that with clean session = FALSE in connect message you don't need to subscribe on next reconnection. It doesn't depend on you but by broker.

Paolo.

Answer (score 1):

You can't be sure, which is why I recommend subscribing to the topics you're interested in at the start of the application every time, also when connecting with `clean_session = False`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already figured that, but then again I wonder what that feature is meant for.

Comment: If you know (by some OOB method?) that your broker has persisted your client (e.g. you know it's an existing broker with storage, etc.) you can save a few octets by not subscribing. Even so, I feel safer subscribing at application start.

Comment: In a lot of cases with GSM/GPRS connection, you pay the bytes transmitted so you have to avoid useless traffic. I think that you have to choose the right broker and trust it (if it is fault tolerant and provides persistent storage) so you can avoid to send subscribe messages on every reconnection even if clean session = false.